# IPhone browser keep Error on specific website

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, safari

I have a website for people to post photo and apply lipstick to that photo. Everything works perfectly at desktop and android. but when using iphone 6 to test, after I post the photo, it will display error on iphone browsers(both Safari and chrome). if I refreshed that page, the result will come out. Any idea about this weird behaviour? What can cause iphone browsers to fail displaying a webpage?
(I've tried all solution i found, like turn javascript off and on, turn off speech and reset datetime)

Safari(A Problem Occurred with this Webpage so it was Reloaded, after reload the result is shown). Chrome(Aw Snap!)

Answer (score 0):

Usually that error (at least in Safari) happens when the webpage takes a long time to load.

Chrome offers [this solution](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) for its browser.

Comment: have any idea about that long time is how long?

Comment: How much does it take to your page to load in your android devices? Are you using a Wi-Fi network or 4G? If you're using a wifi network, why don't you try changing the DNS server to: 8.8.8.8?